# Calculate days between dates but show negative PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I know how to calculate the number of days between two dates as shown below, but, how can I return the difference as a negative number if it's in the past?

This is what I'm using:

```
$today = new DateTime('now'); // today is 2015-09-02

$date1 = new DateTime("2015-08-13"); // 20 days ago

$diff = $today->diff($date1)->format("%a");

echo "diff is $diff"; // shows 20 but I want it to return -20
```

I've tried reversing the variables but it doesn't seem to care about the order.

Comment: what about strtotime to do the same? Or DateTime class is mandatory for you?

Comment: People should read the PHP documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php . It's quite well documented.

Comment: @Abdulla I did say I'd tried reversing the dates in the question

Comment: @Amarnasan Thanks, I did read it - it doesn't mention `%r` anywhere, only `%R` which gives a `+` for positive which I want to avoid

Comment: @darren-sweeney Indeed, well documented, not perfect, though...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DateInterval` has the [`invert` property](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) that specifies whether they're positive or negative.

You can output it like

```
$interval->format("%r%a");
```

`r` stands for

> Sign "-" when negative, empty when positive

See [`DateInterval::format docs`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Comment: I found the "%R" in the examples, but... where did you found the "%r" returning empty when positive? Can't find it.

Comment: You could also put it into **INT** for proper calculation like `(INT)$interval->format("%r%a");`

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = new DateTime('now'); // today is 2015-09-02

$date1 = new DateTime("2015-08-13"); // 20 days ago

$diff = $today->diff($date1)->format("%r%a");
```

Output will be -20. Also you can swap the dates likes following example. Output will be 20.

```
$today = new DateTime('now'); // today is 2015-09-02

$date1 = new DateTime("2015-08-13"); // 20 days ago

$diff = $date->diff($today)->format("%r%a");
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine in my project.

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($firstdate)->diffInDays($seconddate,false) }}
```

output can be : -20

(Laravel)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).